# match.arg equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, r, function, input, arguments

Is there an equivalent in Python to match.arg() as you have in R? Basically limiting the user the choice of inputs one can make for an input function parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it is an old question, but I needed this and there is no answer. So, just for future need:

```
def match_arg(x, lst):
    return [el for el in lst if x in el]
    
lst = ["gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular", "triangular"]
print(match_arg("gauss", lst))
print(match_arg("pauss", lst))
```

Which yield:

```
['gaussian']
[]
```

Kr.

Comment: `match.arg` makes use of `pmatch` which does partial string matching so simple check for element presence in the list wouldn't work